# How to use Language Generation to handle multiple Activities at once in Bot Framework V4

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am trying to create a Language Generation Template where a single response template should be able to send multiple message bubbles in Chat.

For Eg.
Language Generation in Bot Framework allows us to create the below format response:

```
# R1
[Activity
    Text = Basic Test Response
]
```

But this whill send a single message bubble into chat.

I am trying to create a template which can send two messages into chat using a single Language Generation template.

Any inputs are appreciated which can help me in achieving this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this. Each bubble is it's own activity. You can send one activity/message (one bubble) that has line breaks within it, so that each bit of text is separate. But to have separate bubbles, you will need to just send back to back messages (`Send a response`).